# Persistence within jquery .getJSON()

Tags: jquery, json, persistence, getjson

I'm using .getJSON to send a search query to my PHP server and am returning an array which has been json_encode'd.  I'd like to use the resulting object after the jQuery function completes (ideally, pushing it into an array, and use it like any other object elsewhere in the page.

But, the object ceases to exist after the function completes.  This is a success:

```
  var widgets = new Array();

  $.getJSON('/server.php', {query: search.value}, function(response) {
    widgets.push(response);
    alert('value of result's attribute1 is ' + widgets[widgets.length].attribute1);
  });
```

However as soon as I leave the function, widgets.push[length] becomes null, and I can't access anything about the push'ed object.  I would think this would be a copy and not a reference?

My application involves the user doing several of these searches in order to create a list of widgets, and then working between each object's attributes.  Is there an accepted way to make this data persistent after the function completes?

Comment: What is the scope of `widgets`?  Is it (and your call to `getJSON` inside another function?  Try dropping the `var` in front of `widgets = new Array()`; this will ensure you're creating a global variable (so long as `widgets` isn't declared in an outer scope).

Comment: Sorry, should have explained - widgets is global, the first declaration in <script>.  And yes, this call to .getJSON is fired upon a result being added to an autocomplete textbox (the search.value coming from there).

Comment: OK, so then from where do you try to access `widgets` later?

Comment: The access happens after a second widget has been created...and so on as more widgets are pushed on the array.  Would you agree the widgets.push should succeed if placed within the .getJSON's success callback?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The getJSON call is happening asynchronously or independent of the rest of your JavaScript. Your issue is most likely because your getJSON call is not completed before your are attempting to manipulate your widgets array.

You need to make sure any manipulation of widgets occurs after getJSON has completed.

Part of the getJSON syntax allows you to add a callback function when the call succeeds. See http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/. Put your ALL your widget maniuplation code in "success".

Comment: Thank you, this is what I'm looking for - everything's going into the 'success' callback.

Answer (score 1):

I think that you are checking the wrong index of the array.

```
widgets[widgets.length - 1]
```

It might be other things... but this might be it.

Comment: This is right - the index was wrong as well.  Error in my transcription.

Answer (score 0):

Building a 'little' widget and needed to load the jsonP results (widget content ) into the widget container....

This works for me....  ah-one, ah-two, ah-three and four....

1. the global "array" variable

   ```
   var widgetContents = [];
   ```
2. the json request....

   ```
   $.getJSON(jsonp_url, function(results) { 
       $.each(results,  function(i, value) {                      
       widgetContents[i] = value;                          

       // console.log( i + " => " + value);
       });
           var success = true;                                     
   });
   ```
3. debug or catch problems...

   ```
   if ( widgetContents.length == 0 || success != true ) { 
       alert("Opps... something went wrong in the backroom....");
   }
   ```
4. process results....

   ```
   else {
          $.each(widgetContents, function(index, value) {                         
               $('#' + contentsID).append(value);

               /* or whatever you need to do....   */                      
          });
   }
   ```