# Pass php arrray of objects to external javascript file with ajax() OR jQuery.getJSON and jquery?

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, json

This has been asked a lot, but I kind of cant do it alone, new to php and mediocre with jquery.
So, this is my php file

```
<?

            include("dbinfo.inc.php");

mysql_connect($host,$username,$password);
@mysql_select_db($database) or die( "Unable to select database");
$query="SELECT ID, NAME FROM sets";
$result=mysql_query($query);

 while ( $results[] = mysql_fetch_object ( $result ) );
     array_pop ( $results );

$cards = json_encode($results);


echo $cards;
mysql_close();

?>
```

This is the way the resulting json looks :

```
[{"ID":"1","NAME":"Abundant Growth"},{"ID":"2","NAME":"Aggravate"},{"ID":"3","NAME":"Alchemist's Apprentice"},{"ID":"4","NAME":"Alchemist's Refuge"},{"ID":"5","NAME":"Amass the Components"},....
```

For one reason or another, I would like to have my js code in separate js file. I try to access the data with this code:

```
var Sets = new Array();

 jQuery.getJSON("php/mainDB.php", function(data) {
Sets=data
    })
```

and I hope that Sets will be defined as an array of objects ( the same thing I get with Sets = 
Please, help me fix my code, and please post code example. I wont mind if I get an answer using $.ajax() answer, too. Might be helpful in the future :)

Comment: Any errors in the console section .,, Try parsing to to json  .. Sets= $.parseJSON(data)

Comment: No, the console just returns an empty [].

Comment: How does cards look like before being sent back from the server

Comment: Your code is fine. I just tried with this fiddle and it is working fine provided that your php is emitting correct json. http://jsfiddle.net/tariqulazam/KZLnk/ 
What is the issue actually?

Comment: This is a mysql database. the database is static. the output of the php could be seen at magicdb.comli.com. I think my getJSON part is wrong??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect it has to do with asynchronous loading. I would define the Sets variable within the getJSON call:

```
jQuery.getJSON("php/mainDB.php", function(data) {
var Sets = new Array();
Sets=data;
alert(Sets[0].NAME);
})
```

(See a similar issue here: [Persistence within jquery .getJSON()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6222237/persistence-within-jquery-getjson?rq=1))